How to properly use #is_match with eval(...) when creating monitors?
I am trying to create a monitor in Datadog that, when triggered, sends an alert message to a Slack channel and to my e-mail. However, the message should be sent to Slack only during working hours.
At this page in the datadog documentation, under the title "Routing notification to different teams based on time of day", I saw that I could use the following expression:
{{#is_match (eval "int(last_triggered_at_epoch / 3600000 % 24)") "14" "15" "16"}}   @my_Slack_team Handle that should receive notification if time is between 2PM and 5PM UTC {{/is_match}}
However, when I try to use it in a Datadog, I see the following warning:
" In message: is_match argument (eval should be quoted (i.e. "(eval") "

My plan was to write the message to @my_slack_team inside of that is_match tag, but I cannot seem to make it work - I have used double quotes, escapes, and made other attempts with no success.
In the end, I decided to make two separate monitors, one sending alerts to my mail, the other sending alerts to Slack, and configuring a Downtime for the second one, but I am curious if there is a way to use #is_match and eval in the section "Configure notifications and automations" when creating a Datadog monitor, and using only one monitor this way.
I would like to know:
When creating a Datadog Monitor, that sends an alarm to my mail, Can I use an expression that contains #is_match and eval to send a message to a slack team, but only if the alarm is triggered within certain hours of the day?
Or, is there a way to do this by creating only one monitor?
Thanks in advance.

Ignore the UI warning
Despite the UI warning, the documented example does actually work.
I verified this using this monitor definition:

Matching hours changes to alert at the time of writing.
Receiving this notification:

This seems like one of the times where the UI parsing/validating logic (which doesn't block submitting edits) differs from the actual server-side logic (which would block edits/updates if actually invalid). You may wish to submit a ticket to DD to fix the false positive UI warning, although YMMV as to whether that eventually happens or not . Regardless, the structure in the question should match your needs i.e.:
@handle to ping unconditionally

{{#is_match (eval "int(last_triggered_at_epoch / 3600000 % 24)") "14" "15" "16"}}
   Handle/text to only be included in the alert body between 14:00 and 16:59 UTC
{{/is_match}}


Thanks, I did not think about testing the monitor, regardless of the warning at the UI. I will try that!
